# How to implement generator function for one hot encoding

Tags: python, deep-learning, generator, one-hot-encoding

I implemented a generator function to yield one hot encoded vectors but the generator is actually throwing errors

I went for generator function to yield one hot encoded vectors because the latter  would be used as inputs of deep learning lstm model. I am doing this to avoid excessive load and memory failures when trying to create one hot encoding out on data sets of very large size. However,  i am not getting errors with the generator function. I need help to figure out where i am going wrong.

Code before:

```
X = np.zeros((len(sequences), seq_length, vocab_size), dtype=np.bool)
y = np.zeros((len(sequences), vocab_size), dtype=np.bool)
for i, sentence in enumerate(sequences):
    for t, word in enumerate(sentence):
        X[i, t, vocab[word]] = 1
    y[i, vocab[next_words[i]]] = 1
```

Here,

```
sequences = sentences generated from data set
seq_length = length of each sentence(this is constant)
vocab_size = number of unique words in dictionary

My program when run on the large data set produces,

sequences = 44073315
seq_length = 30
vocab_size = 124958
```

So, when the above code is directly used on the latter inputs, it gives beloe error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 206, in <module>
    X = np.zeros((len(sequences), seq_length, vocab_size), dtype=np.bool)
MemoryError
(my_env) [rjagannath1@login ~]$
```

So, i tried creating a generator function(for testing) as below -

```
def gen(batch_size, no_of_sequences, seq_length, vocab_size):
    bs = batch_size
    ns = no_of_sequences
    X = np.zeros((batch_size, seq_length, vocab_size), dtype=np.bool)
    y = np.zeros((batch_size, vocab_size), dtype=np.bool)
    while(ns > bs):
        for i, sentence in enumerate(sequences):
            for t, word in enumerate(sentence):
                X[i, t, vocab[word]] = 1
            y[i, vocab[next_words[i]]] = 1
        print(X.shape())
        print(y.shape())
        yield(X, y)
        ns = ns - bs 

for item in gen(1000, 44073315, 30, 124958):
    print(item)
```

But i get the below error -

```
File "path_of_file", line 247, in gen
    X[i, t, vocab[word]] = 1

IndexError: index 1000 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1000
```

What mistake am i doing in the generator function?

Comment: If batch_size has 1000 elements, then X cannot reach index 1000 (rather 999 because the index starts at 0). If sequences is larger than 1000 elements, that causes the problem

Comment: So i need to reset the batch_size to 999. Am i correct?

Comment: If I understand correctly, your entire looping scheme over there is not good. What is your entire "X" data? is that `sequences`?

Comment: X would be one hot encoded vector for each input word of 30 word sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify as follows in your generator:

```
batch_i = 0
while(ns > bs):
    s = batch_i*batch_size
    e = (batch_i+1)*batch_size
    for i, sentence in enumerate(sequences[s:e]):
```

Basically, you want to run over windows of size `batch_size` so you are making a running slice through `sequences` which appears to be your entire dataset.

you also have to increment `batch_i`, place that just after `yield`, so add
`batch_i+=1`

Comment: Your fix did work. Thank you very much. The generator yields X of shape(1000, 30, 124958) and 
y of shape(1000, 124958). So, if i am correct, the generator object stores the memory for next yield of the input sequences. Am i right? If that is the case, i can use this generator within fit generator function of my lstm model. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the answer to explain better, in case someone comes along with the same problem :) I actually wrote a generator for one hot encoding myself, just a couple of days ago..
If you are happy with the answer, you can press 'accept' on it.

Comment: I did accept.Thanks again. Could you please plus vote my question if i was good with explaining my problem? I hope this post will be beneficial to others.